# how to set a jComponent automatically get the parent size when it resized manually?

Tags: java, swing

I am developing swing application and there I am having JTabpain on top of a JPanel. But when it running if I re-size it manually The Tab-pane will stay as the same. Won't get the size of the parent panel. My layout is group layout. Can some one tell me how to overcome this?

**Before re-sizing**
[image]

**After re-sizing**
[image]

Thanks.

**Edit:**

My code of this:

```
public class BaseFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tabPane;
    // End of variables declaration

    public BaseFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }


    private void initComponents() {

        this.setVisible(true);

        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        tabPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Arcade_logo.JPG"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/title.JPG"))); // NOI18N

        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Windows_Live_Search_logo.png"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 406, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 154, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 24, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(0, 10, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        tabPane.setToolTipText("");
        tabPane.setAutoscrolls(true);
        tabPane.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
        tabPane.setName("Tab"); 

        JPanel homePanel = new JPanel();
        tabPane.add("Home" , homePanel);

        JPanel aUPCPanel = new JPanel();
        tabPane.add("Assemble Your PC" , aUPCPanel);

        JPanel pCPanel = new JPanel();
        tabPane.add("PC" , pCPanel);

        JPanel laptopPanel = new JPanel();
        tabPane.add("LapTop" , laptopPanel);

        JPanel usPanel = new JPanel();
        tabPane.add("About us" , usPanel);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(tabPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 786, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel4Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(tabPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 534, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        tabPane.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: Posting some code would help you get a faster answer. Better yet, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `BorderLayout` to panel to which you add your `JTabbedPane`. And add your `JTabbedPane` like next:

```
panel.add(tabbedPane,BorderLayout.CENTER)
```

`tabbedPane` is your `JTabbedPane`.

In that case your tabbedPane will be resizing.

Also read about different [`LayoutManager`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and choose appropriate.

Comment: too hard job for users that works only with JComponents dropped from pallete

Comment: Yeah, as for me `GroupLayout` really hard to edit, simplier to write by hand.